# Why does Jenkins reassign a variable from .env when running pytest autotests?

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, pytest, .env

I have Jenkins to run autotests on python with preliminary creation of `.env` file. In turn, Jenkins is deployed on Windows:

[image]

At first I didn't understand why python gives an error that SERVICE_ID is not `int`:

```py
def create_gpd_draft(self, employee, manager_token, service_id=int(os.getenv('SERVICE_ID')),
E   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jenkins'
```

But then I debugged and found out that Jenkins substitutes the value "jenkins" in the variable name.

What could this be related to?

```py
pprie = os.getenv('SERVICE_ID')
assert pprie == 13, f'What is equal to  {pprie}'
AssertionError: What is equal to jenkins
assert 'jenkins' == 13
```

[image]

I am using selemium+pytest bundle to create autotests on a project. Also, Jenkins is selected for daily runs, which substitutes a strange variable value into `.env`

Comment: Aside from `SERVICE_ID`, are you able to query the other env variables without issue?

Comment: Yes, and they are presented correctly